# Flutter: How to pass data between screens?

Tags: flutter

How can I change the `visibility` of a button on `screen "X"` from a button on `screen "Y"`.

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that you want to modify a view of another screen while in another?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter, Navigator 2.0: How to return data from a screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66279804/flutter-navigator-2-0-how-to-return-data-from-a-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One popular approach (using the `provider` architecture) would be something like this:

Define a `provider` that handles all the logic and holds your data:

```
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool showMyButton = false;

  MyProvider() {}

  void showButton() {
    showMyButton = true;
    // This line notifies all consumers
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void refresh() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

To access the `provider` everywhere you need to register it:

```dart
void main() => runApp(
      // You can wrap multiple providers like this
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(create: (_) => MyProvider()),
        ],
        child: const MyApp(),
      ),
    );
```

On the button that you want to control you can use a `Consumer` to listen to the `providers` values:

```
Consumer<MyProvider>(builder: (_, model, __) {
     return Visibility(
             visible: model.showMyButton,
             child: MaterialButton(...),
     );
})
```

Now in your second screen you can access that provider with:

```
Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false)
                        .showButton();
```

**However you might have to call `notifyListener` one more time** when returning from `screen Y` to `screen X`:

```dart
await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ScreenY()));
Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false).refresh();
```

Keep in mind that there is a lot more to `provider` so please have a look at their official [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Also be aware of the fact that there are [easier ways](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data) to just pass data between screens but you will often arrive at a point where you will need a better way of managing state and `provider` provides just that ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data via push and pop of navigation. Or else use ChangeNotifier class to notify the state of button easily.